# wso2 api manager schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed- The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am using WSO2 API manager 3.2.0 and I am faced with a probelm when I configured load balancing with Nginx and multi instance, as following :

```
schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_UNTRUSTED_ROOT (0x80090325) - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.
```

Could you please guide me how to solve it? I know that is SSL_Certificate issue and for example we can invoke api wit -inactive  or deisable ssl verification in post man, but I want to solve it. I have studied in document that there is `wso2carbon.jks` that is default keystore , so how to solve problem with defualt key store?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mentioned error is happening since you are using Self-Signed certificates in your environment. The `cURL` doesn't trust the Self-Signed certificates when trying to invoke the APIs. Therefore, if you want to overcome this behavior, you have to generate a CA-signed certificate and configure the environment.

You can refer to the following [docs](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/install-and-setup/setup/security/configuring-keystores/keystore-basics/creating-new-keystores/#adding-ca-signed-certificates-to-keystores) to generate and configure CA-signed certificate with WSO2 API Manager.

Furthermore, if this is your local setup, you can move forward with the `-k` flag in the `cURL` command to bypass and make an insecure connection with the API Manager.

Comment: Thanks, now by insecure or bypassing I invoked api, but in devportal I can not invoke api, against postman. What is the problem?

Comment: the  devportal doesn't trust self signed certificate?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on the scenario? Are you facing issues when trying to invoke the API from the Postman? Or are you facing issues when invoking from the Swagger console in the Devportal? Further, are you observing any errors in the wso2carbon.log? If the self-signed certificate is trusted from the Browser, then the Swagger console will be able to invoke the API as expected from the Devportal. In addition, also check whether you are seeing any errors in the Browser's console tab (anything related to CORS)

Comment: I create new question in following address : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68710688/typeerror-failed-to-fetch-issues-when-invoking-api-from-the-swagger-console-in @Athiththen