# TypeError: Failed to fetch Issues when invoking API from the Swagger console in the Devportal

Tags: wso2-api-manager

when invoking API  from the Swagger console in the Devportal I am faced with a problem

```
TypeError: Failed to fetch Issues
```

But, When I invoke with Curl in -insecure, it successfully works, so what is the problem with wagger console in the Devportal?
this is browser console output :
[image]
[image]

But in postman & Curl after remove port number, it works as following :
[image]
[image]

Comment: It seems that when you are trying to invoke the API without the port you were able to get the response. Therefore, can you update the Environment configurations in the TOML configuration without the Port and try out the scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the shared cURL outputs, when you are trying to invoke the API with `:8243`, it is getting `Connection Refused`. Therefore, can you try updating the Gateway Environment configuration without the port and try out the scenario?

Given below is the TOML configuration without the port mentioned for the `https_endpoint`

```
[[apim.gateway.environment]]
name = "Default"
...
http_endpoint = "http://localhost:${http.nio.port}"

# remove the port section
https_endpoint = "https://gw.am.wso2.com"
...
```

Once updating the configurations, save and restart the server and try out the scenario.

Comment: thanks. my problem solved. just what about following config, should I remove port in "ws " ?  ws_endpoint = "ws://gw.am.wso2.com:9099"
wss_endpoint = "wss://gw.am.wso2.com:8099"

Comment: Yes, you can remove those if you have mentioned the routing configurations in the Nginx. You can try invoking a WebSocket API and update the configurations.

Comment: As following wso2 document, I did't find any thing about config 9099 or 8099, so  I have't mentioned 9099 port in nginx server config.

Comment: The Nginx configuration presented in the API Manager docs contains the routings for only the REST APIs. Therefore, if you are planning to deploy WebSocket APIs and make it available, we have to create another routing configuration for this set and add it to the Nginx.